# What linux is easy to attach to a windows domain

Tags: linux, active-directory

for a development test bed I need to attach ANY linux machiene to a test AD Domain and do single sign on through it. Is there a Linux Distro that is easy to connect to AD?

Comment: I'm just looking for ANY linux not "the best" linux for use in AD. mostly looking for "super easy to attach to the domain" because all i need it to do is attach with the least fuss on my part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

perhaps it was a silly question, [this was stupid simple.](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/likewise-open.html)

EDIT: **Package is dead**, rebranded per [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen)

Ubuntu-10.04:

```
sudo apt-get install likewise-open
sudo domainjoin-cli join example.com Administrator
```

then ssh 'DOMAIN\username'@hostname and poof single sign on magic!

EDIT: today (June 2010) the likewise-open package is missing a dependency on psmisc so you have to run this *first*:

```
sudo apt-get install psmisc
```

if you already installed likewise-open then:

```
sudo apt-get purge likewise-open
sudo apt-get install likewise-open
```

EDIT1:
need to add the AD DNS server as the hosts dns server *first*, and set the hostname.
EDIT2:
need to make sure the reverse dns is correct.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS, just open a terminal and type "setup" - then follow the instructions

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL or CentOS 4 or newer the following command will reconfigure the auth system and join AD.  You can remove the flag for PAM /etc/security/access.conf if you don't want to configure it but I find that not everyone with a valid AD account should be allowed onto every host, only members of certain AD groups.  I believe there is also a flag to configure winbind to allow disconnected authentication, for laptops and such which need to log in when not on the network.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/authconfig-tui \
 --enablewinbind \
 --enablewinbindauth \
 --enablemkhomedir \
 --enablepamaccess \
 --enablelocauthorize \
 --smbsecurity=ads \
 --smbrealm=DOMAIN.COM \
 --smbworkgroup=DOMAIN \
 --smbservers=dc.domain.com \
 --winbindtemplatehomedir="/home/%U" \
 --winbindtemplateshell="/bin/bash" \
 --enablewinbindusedefaultdomain \
 --kickstart \
 --winbindjoin=DomainAdminAcct
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually any Linux distro with a current Samba install should be able to be joined to a Windows domain. As mentioned Likewise on Ubuntu makes it extremely easy to get it up and working but I found that it worked best if I didn't have Likewise *AND* Samba installed otherwise they tried to fight one another.

Samba would be a more involved installation process as Likewise appears to be solely a NSS plugin of sorts while Samba adds the whole kitchen sink along with it allowing file and printer sharing to be made available.